# Hint for the integral

Tags: definite-integrals

I was trying to compute the following integral but got stuck at the starting point. Can anyone provide a valuable hint for the evaluation of this integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{9}e^{-x^{2}} dx$ ?

Comment: Integration by parts isn't helping? Here's a hint: Say that $u=x^2 \to \frac{1}{2}du=x dx$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**

Let $t=x^2$ and use the Gamma function.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: why is the Gamma function helpful? the result is a polynomial multiplied by the exponential function

Answer (score 0):

for the indefinite integral $\int x^9e^{-x^2}dx$ the ansatz
$$e^{-x^2}(Ax^8+Bx^6+Cx^4+Dx^2+E)$$ and compute the coeficients by differentiation with respect to $x$